# ubuntu server 21.10 installed on raspberry pi zero 2 w

Tags: networking, drivers, server, wireless, raspberrypi

According to the information in [this website](https://ubuntu.com/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-with-ubuntu-server-support-is-here)

It should be possible to run Ubuntu server x32 on raspberry pi zero 2 w. I buy RPI and I did install this image using raspberry pi imager and downloaded the proper image from the ubuntu website. I used the appropriate 21.10 x32 image for raspberry from the [ubuntu website.](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) No auto configuration has occurred. after installing raspberry pi os, wifi works fine but the ubuntu system has no network interfaces. the system boots, but to my surprise, there are no networking interfaces such as wifi. The `ip a` command only points to lo (loopback device). How to add a wifi interface in such a situation? there is no network so I cannot install anything. I tried the ubuntu 22.04 but it is exactly the same.

commands: `ip a` and `sudo lshw -class network` and `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` are visible in the image below:

[image: screen]

Comment: What's the output of `ls /sys/class/net`?

Comment: `ls /sys/class/net` shows only `lo`